# How to create a Google web app using Google Apps Script, React, and MobX

Tags: reactjs, google-apps-script, mobx

I found [`react-google-apps-script` project on GitHub](https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script), and it seems to be able to make my dreams of a React-based Google Apps Script project a reality. For a while, since I learned React (and MobX), I've been wanting to use it inside Google Apps Script projects!

Per the documentation, however, it seems to only work on dialog windows... :'(

That being said, I have a freelancing client who is looking for a UI that can interact with her Google Sheets, to which the most reasonable approach would be to create a web app. I've created Google Apps Script based web apps in the past, in fact it was my very first exposure to it. It seems like they only support raw HTML templates and jQuery .

However, knowing all that I know now, I'd like to create a simple React + MobX MVVM-based web app on the Google Apps Script. How can we use this project to get that done?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I should have read more carefully! This is embarassing!!

From looking at [`src/server/ui.js`](https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script/blob/master/src/server/ui.js), I see that is how the main use case, injecting React project into the modals in Google Apps Script projects that control Google Spreadsheets, even gets to happen.

Here is the code from that file:

```
export const onOpen = () => {
  const menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('My Sample React Project') // edit me!
    .addItem('Sheet Editor', 'openDialog')
    .addItem('Sheet Editor (Bootstrap)', 'openDialogBootstrap')
    .addItem('About me', 'openAboutSidebar');

  menu.addToUi();
};

export const openDialog = () => {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog-demo')
    .setWidth(600)
    .setHeight(600);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Sheet Editor');
};

export const openDialogBootstrap = () => {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog-demo-bootstrap')
    .setWidth(600)
    .setHeight(600);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Sheet Editor (Bootstrap)');
};

export const openAboutSidebar = () => {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar-about-page');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
};
```

It is worth noting that this will transpile to the back-end Google Apps Script code.

This means that we could customize this and make this more general, by editing out the `onOpen` method. I see it is developer's responsibility to do that :P

Great project! It's easy to follow, and I can see how I can make this my own, with MobX and MVVM!